# Pass variable from blade to blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm new to uusing Laravel blade templating.

I have a bootstrap modal that I need to show on button click, also, I need to pass some values on that click event.

For example.

On my parent blade: *(btw, its a nested modal blade)*
**modal_1.blade.php**

```xml
<div class="modal" id="modal1">
    ...
    
    @foreach($templates as $key => $val)
        <button onclick="previewItem($templates[$key]['color'])">
        </button>
    @endforeach
        
</div>
<script>
    const previewItem = (color) => {
        // how to pass this `color` to the child modal blade
    }
</script>
```

and the child blade modal
**modal_2.blade.php**

```xml
<div class="modal" id="modal2">
    // how to access passed variable from modal1 ?
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see where you include modal2 file in modal1 file. You are missing `@include` or you don't really embed modal_2 in modal_1. Variables are passed through `@include()`.

Comment: @DanielW., I have it inside the `modal1`. However, I don' think I can use that javascript variable in php.

Comment: Variables from the HTML can be passed upon the next request (ajax, form with post, link or form with get).

Comment: Did you take a look at the source to make sure everything works as expected. I'd assume `<button onclick="previewItem($templates[$key]['color'])">` should be `<button onclick="previewItem('{{$templates[$key]['color'])}}'">, since it's Blade. And `'` because it should a JS string

Answer (score 0):

you can create a component and inject here your variables:

```
@component('components.updateMyUserModal' , ['modal_id' => $account->id , 'modal_title' => $account->title , 'modal_body' => $aContext,  ] )
                    @endcomponent
```

Answer (score -1):

one file needs to be inside the other, after that, you need to use cookie, to store the variable's value in the previous modal, when you click on the button to select the value, make by javascript a cookie that saves this value and on the next blade you recover that value and uses.

How to use:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Better link to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) than [w3schools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com) :-)